# Can Ubuntu Phone run on LG Optimus L4 E440?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, devices, lg

I have a lg optimus l4 ii E44. with 3.8 inch screen 512mb of RAM and want to know if phone runs ubuntu.
Thank

Answer (score 0):

There is an official list here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

If your device is not in this list, you will have to port it by yourself, write drivers, etc.

Comment: It does not appear. How I can do that you say?

Comment: Write drivers etc?

Comment: Yes. How do I write drivers?

Comment: It is that I am a rookie

Comment: If you don't know, what I mean, you aren't able to do it. So you should get a supported phone, that will be easier.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll see if another makes rom or I'll get the L90

Comment: Please set my answer as "answer", so other users know it's answered.

Comment: Please don't forget to set it as answer.